# Looking for books on Information Science, Information Retrieval

Tags: information-retrieval

Here's what I have on my list so far.  I'd like to know of others in the same vein, perhaps more technical, perhaps less

Blown to Bits: Your Life, Liberty, and Happiness After the Digital Explosion - Ableson, Leeden, and Lewis
Glut: Mastering Information Through the Ages - Wright
Information Rules - Varian and Shapiro
Web Dragons: Inside the Myths of Search Engine Technology - Witten, Gori, and Numerico

There are a few I've seen on text mining, they include
Web Data Mining - Liu
Modern Information Retrieval - Baeza-Yates, Ribiero-Neto

Also looking for blog recs like
http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/blog/
http://www.econlib.org/library/Enc/Information.html

or papers like
[The Discovery of Structural Form](http://www.psy.cmu.edu/~ckemp/papers/kempt08.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

- "SIGIR" - the conference
- "TREC" - the conference
- Baeza-Yates, Ribeiro-Neto, "Modern Information Retrieval" (1999)
- Witten, "Managing Gigabytes" (1999)
- van Rijsbergen, "Information Retrieval" (1979)

are the obvious "bibles" (as mentioned above).

- Büttcher, Clarke, Cormack, "Information Retrieval: Implementing and Evaluating Search Engines" (2010)

is an interesting new textbook (student-level), full of biliographic references. It contains a good explanation of parallel retrieval algorithms (sample chapter).

- Croft, Metzler, Strohman, "Search Engines: Information Retrieval in Practice" (2009)

has good reviews; I didn't like it too much (read the sample chapters on Croft's homepage).

- Voorhees, Harman, "Trec: Experiment and Evaluation in Information Retrieval" (2009)

is a good introduction to the TREC approach in evaluating IR.

- Langville, Meyer, "Google's Pagerank and Beyond: The Science of Search Engine Rankings" (2006)

explains how to efficently compute PageRank.

Answer (score 4):

[Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://www-csli.stanford.edu/~hinrich/information-retrieval-book.html) seems to be the recommended text these days for the underlying technology; it was released in 2008 and I haven't read it yet. (The full text is free online.) *Managing Gigabytes*, as TimB recommended, is my favorite older book; it's much better written than *Modern Information Retrieval*, though that's also worth a look. There's more you can find with [the obvious search](http://www.google.com/search?q=information+retrieval).

Answer (score 3):

[Managing Gigabytes - Witten, Moffat, and Bell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605703): a quite detailed look at some of the technologies behind information retrieval, text and image compression. (Disclaimer: my university supervisor is the second author.)

You should also know about ACM's [SIGIR](http://www.sigir.org/), which organises an annual conference on information retrieval, and has a [mailing list](http://www.sigir.org/sigirlist/) as well.

Comment: thanks.  i was going to put that book on my original list.  I appreciate the links.

Answer (score 0):

As Book [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://www-csli.stanford.edu/~hinrich/information-retrieval-book.html) as mentioned.

I think, the best advanced information are the publications found in several academic sites and the conference papers (SIGIR, CIKM, SPIRE, WWW009, ...).

Ex.:

- [Poly edu](http://cis.poly.edu/suel/papers/papers.htm)
- [Melbourne](http://www.cs.mu.oz.au/~jz/Papers.html)
- [Melbourne](http://www.cs.mu.oz.au/~alistair/abstracts/)
- [Glasgow](http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/terrier/publications.html)
- [University of Waterloo](http://www.wumpus-search.org/publications.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Information Retrieval - Implementing and Evaluating Search Engines** has been published by MIT press in 2010 and is a very good book on gaining practical knowledge of Information Retrieval. Stefan Buttcher, Charles Clarke and Gordon Cormack are the authors of this book. Buttcher was Clarke's doctoral student, and Clarke was Cormack's doctoral student. Altogether, they have combined around 50 years of their IR research and experience in this book. Its a must read !!!